# What are the requirements for android applications be run on ubuntu?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I'm working on a project that requires developing an android application for a galaxy tab, and after that, develop an application with the same purpose that runs on a desktop computer using Ubuntu 10.04.

My goal is to avoid doing the same thing over for a different platform. I guess that I can't have the exact same application running on android and ubuntu (without an android emulator).

Assuming I program it with java, what would be the requirements or which design suggestion would you provide so that I can reuse most of the code for both applications?

I'm more into the C++ world, what I'd try to do is to create some classes with the high-level an platform independent code, and then what would have to be rewritten is just the platform specific code. But I certainly have no idea of how to do it with java.

Comment: What if you make a web app? You get both platforms for "free"!

Comment: Can't, because I need to access bluetooth on both the computer and the android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to split your code into manageable layers.. & use these layers as dependencies for your project... with careful planning you would have a very minimal set of changes to be made for the project...

there are a lot of articles on the web to guide you through these things.. having said that design boils down to how you categorize your app..

usually we have 3layers
1. DAO -> mainly dealing with data access (like db access etc).
2. Service -> relating to Business Logic, this sits on top of dao.
3. Presentation -> relating to UI (like struts, velocity etc.,)

for android app,
in your case you can replace your DAO with webservice calls, your service might need a bit of tweaking & your presentation layer needs to be built from scratch.

hope this helps.

Comment: I already planned on doing something like this, basically following MVC as BryanH said. My question was more oriented towards the implementation, I have little experience programming in Java and I don't know which libraries are available both in java for Ubuntu and java for Android. For instance, in C++ I'd assume that the STL would be available in most of the platforms, what about Java?

Comment: This is something similar to what I was looking for:  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-vs-android-apis/504

Answer (score 2):

If you design your code following the MVC model, you can keep your business logic (provided you don't use any android libraries) and maybe your controllers. The views will change, but if you adhere to MVC, your required efforts will be minimal (compared to if you **don't** follow MVC).